# Poster presentation at an International conference

Tags: conference

I am preparing a poster for presenting in an international conference. Could anyone please suggest whether I can use merged confocal image or should I put single channel images and then merged, like we put while publishing papers.i am using 300dpi tiff images. Is this format ok?

Comment: It's your poster. Follow the instructions given my the conference. These differ between conferences. For the image, it really depends what your final goal is, it is to show different things in each color channel or you just want to show the final image. Thin about what the goal of the poster is.

Answer (score 3):

The poster presentations that I visited in the past all had tripods with physical posters of a given maximum size, with the presenter hovering near-by. It was left to the presenters what to do with their space. This would include how to generate images.

If this is an electronic poster presentation, then you should have been given instructions, but again, I would expect that what you do with the space is up to you.